# How to setup socket.io in Android properly?

Tags: android

I'm building a webRTC based communication application in Android. It has a chat application inside and I keep getting the error about socketIO when running the test in the real device and the emulator.

I download "socket.io-client-java-master"file from "https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java" and put the dependencies in pom.xml and bundle.gradle file with the instruction. However I think that there is somthing I miss now. Below is the error code.

What is the proper way to install socketIO.java? I hope that I can get some hint from many experts' opinions.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/github/nkzawa/socketio/client/IO$Options;
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bj.e(Unknown Source)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bj.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bg.connect(Unknown Source)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bz.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO$Options" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sungpah.sungpahfirst-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.sungpah.sungpahfirst-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bj.e(Unknown Source)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bj.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bg.connect(Unknown Source)
            at sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.bz.run(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO$Options
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Below is my gradle setup status.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sungpah.sungpahfirst"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.jni.srcDirs = []
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

I didn't change pom.xml file from what I downloaded.

Comment: maybe this can help u [link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaMsKXQSUJE he use this library